# How to make a column of Flaks table in html clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask, jinja2

I have a table created in html page of the application as below.

```html
<html>

<table  id="myTable" class="sortable" {{ table }} </table>

</html>
```

One of the columns in the table has github urls. I want to make those urls 
clickable so that clicking on them will redirect me to the github location.

Please let me know how should i do that.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I want the urls to be from the column in the table. that is clicking on the github urls in the "github url" column should take me to that github location. Also I am new bit new to the html. could you integrate the change to my code and provide the full code.

Answer (score 0):

You're speaking about how to use a linked element?

```
<a href="http://link.com">YOUR LINKED TEXT</a>
```

Comment: Hi, I want the urls to be from the column in the table. that is clicking on the github urls in the "github url" column should take me to that github location. Also I am new bit new to the html. could you integrate the change to my code and provide the full code.